# Kafka Java API fail to produce a message but didn't throw an exception

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using the Java KafkaProducer API to produce a Kafka message.

I'm calling the `send` method that returns a Future and then a `get` to block and wait the result.

I was expecting that when the Producer failed to send a message, it will throw an exception but it's not happening.

I have just a log saying:
`Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 218444 : {TOPIC=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}`

the message wasn't produced, but the API didn't return an error so I didn't have the opportunity to take an action and the message was lost.

How can I handle situations like this one?

Just to clarify, I'm not worried with the specific error because it was a temporary error. I'm worried because reading the API documentation it says that `.send(message).get` will thrown an exception when fail to send a message but it didn't happen.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A tip: if you provide a link to the API documentation page you're looking at, that will improve your question's quality and likelihood of being answered.

Comment: Producer API doesn't send messages to the broker immediately. It sends it to an internal batch until the producer is `.flush()`'d. You won't get an exception to the broker until that request is made... You should also probably use the `OnCompletionListener` instead which gives you access to any Exception that's had

Comment: Can you share your code and the producer configuration?

Comment: Although we need more information regarding your producer, I'm almost sure that the producer was able to produce message. Topic leader not available seems to be issue in topic configuration. One or more partitions in that topic is missing leader. Please check the topic partitions.